# CustomPainter called endlessly?

Tags: flutter, mapbox

My CustomPainter was working fine with the [old Mapbox plugin](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps), but switching to the [new Mapbox plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter) causes its paint method to get called over and over, without any screen changes or shouldRepaint being called.

My CustomPainter is over the map using a Stack widget.

What is causing this? Or is there a way to guard against it?

Comment: are you passing any `Listenable` in `super(repaint: ...)` in your custom painter?

Comment: I'm not calling super.repaint at all, and I haven't changed my CustomPainter code that was working with the old plugin.

Comment: SO won't let me edit my last comment; here's the fix: I don't have a ctor at all, so I'm not calling the super ctor, and I haven't changed my CustomPainter code that was working with the old plugin.

Comment: looks like a mapbox bug then, the only way to prevent endless `paint` method being called is to wrap your custom painter with `RepaintBoundary`